# Themable User Controls in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls, themes

How can I create a UserControl in WPF that has a basic default style but can also easily themed when needed?

Do you have some good guidelines, blog entries or example that explain this specific topic?

Thank you in advance,
Marco

Answer (score 7):

In WPF themes are simply a set of XAML files each containing a **ResourceDictionary** which holds the **Style** and **Template** definitions that apply to the controls used in the application. A theme file could look like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:MyApp.UserControls">

  <!-- Standard look for MyUserControl -->
  <Style x:Key="Standard" TargetType="{x:Type uc:MyUserControl}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="22" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="10" />
  </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Support for themes in a WPF application must be explicitly enabled by adding the following attribute to the assembly:

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo(
  ResourceDictionary.None,
  ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly
 )]
```

This will instruct WPF to look for an **embedded resource** file called *themes\generic.xaml* to determine the default look of the application's controls.

Note that when the **theme-specific dictionaries are contained separate files** than the application's assembly, style and template resources must use a *composite key*, which tells WPF which assembly contains the control that the style/template applies to. So the previous example should be modified to:

```
<ResourceDictionary
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:MyApp.UserControls;assembly=MyApp">

  <!-- Standard look for MyUserControl in the MyApp assembly -->
  <Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey {x:Type uc:MyUserControl}, Standard}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="22" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="10" />
  </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: @SvenHecht Thanks for pointing that out. I removed the dead link reference.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135986.aspx

It talks about how to write a control that you can change with a ControlTemplate, like the built in controls.

Comment: Link is dead :( Do you remember the article?

Comment: I think you must either delete this answer or find the article.

Comment: @yola you are right, I'll delete the answer when I'm at my computer (I'm using the mobile app now and can't find the delete button)